# I bought the reputation upgrade, why can't I delete answers?

Tags: support, unicoins

I toiled and laboured for my 90 unicorn dollars to be able to get the reputation to delete answers, but I can't! Isn't this a scam?

Comment: Why the negative score? This seems such a nice, thoughtful question with a straight single answer as desired by stackoverflow!

Comment: I am also having this problem. My reputation is 54k, but I cannot access the moderator tools. What gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not a scam.

90 **unicoins** will allow you to delete answers, but 90 "unicorn dollars" will just allow you to make friends with unicorns who need money.

Comment: You have a very good point. Unicorn Dollars are just a pretend play currency with no value.

Comment: Hey, I paid $1000 via wire transfer for unicorn dollars? Can I get my money back?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes. My friend the deposed prince is planning to help you cash in on your investment.

Answer (score 11):

You are probably under the effect of "Cut everyone's rep" power-up from a nearby user. Step back and try again.